# Kotlin : On camera move end

Tags: android, google-maps, events, kotlin

I'd like to know how to detect when the camera finishes its move or detect when the user remove his finger from the screen after that the camera has been moved.

For now I have this small listener :

```
 mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener {
   val coords = mMap.cameraPosition.target
   getData(coords)   
}
```

But it's trigger everytime the camera move (basically, it's its normal behavior).

But I' doing a api call with **getData(coords)**, so the api is triggered every time the camera moves (so it makes a lot of call in a few second)...

Comment: Take a look at [`onCameraIdle()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener.html#onCameraIdle()).

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`onCameraIdle()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener#onCameraIdle()) and [`GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener) instead of `OnCameraMoveListener`:

```
mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener {
   val coords = mMap.cameraPosition.target
   getData(coords)   
}
```